# Measuring Div Heights in Angular After Render

Tags: javascript, html, angular

A bit of an angular newbie! In our Angular app, we have a series of divs of various heights that need to be measured, to the pixel, so that when the measurement of the divs hits a specific value, let's say every 1000px, it will automatically insert a new div to act like a page break and force the series of original divs down to the next 'page' of 1000px. In javascript, getting the heights would be easy to achieve, but as far as I can tell, there's no way for the script to properly talk back to the angular app to make this work. I'm aware that angular might need to render the divs twice (once originally, get the heights, then render again) but I'm honestly not certain how to go about this.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to possibly make this work? Thank you!

Example:

```
<div class="original" style="height: 325px">
<div class="original" style="height: 225px">
<div class="original" style="height: 745px">
<div class="original" style="height: 325px">
```

So here's my original bunch of divs as they are hanging out in angular. From their heights, you can see that when you hit the 745px div, it would go over my 1000px limit for a page. If the 745px div goes to a new page, trying to add the 345px div to that page would go over 1000px, so I would need another page break. I'm looking for it to result in the following:

```
<div class="original" style="height: 325px">
<div class="original" style="height: 225px">
<div class="pageBreak">
<div class="original" style="height: 745px">
<div class="pageBreak">
<div class="original" style="height: 325px">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ViewChild` to get a parent element, use it to get children elements on `AfterViewInit` event, get their heights and set some new values according to your logic with `Renderer2`:

Template:

```
<div #mainContent>
  <div class="gantt section"></div>
  <div class="list section"></div>
</div>
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Renderer2, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class Whatever implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('mainContent') contentEl: ElementRef;

  constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2,
  ) {}

  ...

  // set the two main sections half of the available height
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const ganttSection = this.contentEl.nativeElement.querySelector('.gantt .section');
    const listSection = this.contentEl.nativeElement.querySelector('.list .section');

    const initHeight = this.contentEl.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
    this.renderer.setStyle(ganttSection, 'height', `${initHeight / 2}px`);
    this.renderer.setStyle(listSection, 'height', `${initHeight / 2}px`);
  }

}
```

Or assign each element an id (angular-specific like `#theid`, not an ordinary `id` attribute) and extract them all by `@ViewChildren` so you can avoid the `querySelector` calls, the rest is the same (just not sure if the `renderer.setStyle` accepts the `elementRef` or `elementRef.nativeElement`).

As for the `pageBreak` elements - haven't needed to add elements dynamically yet (outside "generators" like `*ngFor`), I'd suggest adding them beforehand with either `[hidden]="aFlag"` or `*ngIf="aFlag"` with the flags set in the `ngAfterViewInit` according to calculation results (the former just modifies the `display` property, the latter removes the element from the DOM). [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) has methods for DOM manipulation like `appendChild`, `insertBefore`, etc. and element creation though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div #id class="original" style="height: 325px">

import {ElementRef,Renderer2} from '@angular/core';
@ViewChild('id') el:ElementRef;

constructor(private rd: Renderer2) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log(this.rd); 


  this.el.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
}
```